# select date from datepicker after i want next year date in next field

Tags: javascript, php, html

from date selected by the datepicker in dd-mm--yy format after this i need next year date with -1 day..i.e From:29-07-2016 then To:28-07-2016 like this...please guyz help me..i m sharing my source code

```js
$('#oldDate').on('change', function(e){
  var oldDate = new Date(this.value);    
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
  
  
  
  $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
  oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate()-1);
  oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear()+1);

 var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = oldDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
        
//        var today = oldDate.(day)+"-"+(month)+"-"+getFullYear();
//        alert(today);
        $('#new').val(today);
```

```html
<p class="left">
            <label for="from">FROM:</label>
            <input type="text" name="from" id="oldDate"  class="datepicker"/>
          </p>
          <p class="pull-right">
            <label for="to">TO:</label>
            <input type="text" name="to" id="new">
          </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use datepicker and then use on change function to make work

JS:

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
 }).datepicker("setDate", "0");

 $('#oldDate').click(function() {
   $('#oldDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
 });

 $('#oldDate').on('change', function(e) {

   console.log(this.value)
   var x = this.value;
   var from = x.split("-");
   var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
   var oldDate = new Date(f);
   $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
   oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() - 1);
   oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear() + 1);
   console.log(oldDate)

   var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

   var today = (day) + "-" + (month) + "-" + oldDate.getFullYear();

   //        var today = oldDate.(day)+"-"+(month)+"-"+getFullYear();
   //        alert(today);
   $('#new').val(today);
 });
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKBZmN

Comment: Its giving `NaN-aN-aN`

Comment: Please check updated code pen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXjVbJ, i see today format was set different

Comment: Please check the updated codepen with format - mm/dd/yyyy - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Eypwxk

Comment: thanx..it working...bt is it possible to get the from date in dd--mm--yy....i tried bt giving Nan-aN-Na in to date...

Comment: updated post with updated code and codepen .. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: and i m doing for updation so in from field i m echo the last updated date bt after the click on field it display calendar of last updated day....i.e from;16-09-2015 so after click on field it display calendar of 9 month with the 16 date..is any solution for to diaplay the current date calendar after click

Comment: @Neil,do you want to reset the from date to today's date on clicking from date ?

Comment: yeah...exactly...after click on field it should display today date with calendar instead of date is present in text field

Comment: Add on click function to oldDate - $('#oldDate').click(function(){
    $('#oldDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});

Comment: updated Codepen and post.. Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var dt = new Date('2016/12/10');
     var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
     var day = dt.getDate()-1;
     var year = dt.getFullYear()+1;
     alert(month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
   </script>
```